# Get the Page Content,without generating HTML

Tags: pages, content, the-content

I want to get the page content (so i can parse the tags/short-codes in it), but i don't want to output the result itself to the browser (i.e. echo=0).

I tried get_the_content(); but its the same deal.

Comment: `get_the_content()` does not echo output, it is returned. So what exactly is your problem with it?

Comment: It doesn't eval the shortcodes in the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you doing your code parsing? If you're doing it directly in the template file, inside the Loop, then you should be using `get_the_content()`.

However, it might be more efficient to filter `the_content()`, via the `the_content` filter. e.g. in `functions.php`:

```
function mytheme_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    // add code here to filter the_content
    // which is contained in the $content variable,
    // then return $content
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'mytheme_filter_the_content' );
```

**EDIT**

If, for whatever reason, you just want to parse `the_content()`, pull out the shorcodes, and *execute* them, use `do_shortcode()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)). e.g.:

```
<?php
$page_content = get_the_content();
$page_shortcodes = array() // ...some array that includes whatever shortcodes you found

foreach ( $page_shortcodes as $page_shortcode ) {
    do_shortcode( $page_shortcode );
}
?>
```

Comment: Im using a template file, but i just want to get the page content and eval the short-codes in the page, without generating the HTML.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
         query_posts( 'type=post&posts_per_page=1' );

           if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

           ?> 

             <?php the_content(); ?>

             <?php endwhile;
                               endif; 

              wp_reset_query();
              ?>
```

Comment: Can you explain the answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$page_data = get_page( $page_id ); 
$page_content = $page_data->post_content;
```

Comment: I can get it that's not the problem, the problem is evaluating the short-tags. This just get the plain text.